# Firebase RTDB - Get document ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how can i retrieve document IDs in a `useEffect` using firebase realtime database?

This works great but however i need every single document id aswell.
[image]

[image]

Comment: People don't know from where is `useEffect()` function. Edit and add correct tags to your question.

Comment: My useEffect has nothing to do with my question really. All im asking how i would retrieve all the documents fetched IDs on the onValue.

Comment: Try `snapshot.id()`

Comment: Or snapshot.key

Comment: Going forward, please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can get keys from array in RTDB:

```js
onValue(dbRef, (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
    const childKey = childSnapshot.key;
    const childData = childSnapshot.val();
    // ...
  });
}, {
  onlyOnce: true
});
```

You need to get to childSnapshots using forEach or for loop.